# fatal: Could not change back to '/usr/local/www': No such file or directory

Tags: git

I'm trying to run `git init` on my `www` directory which results in the following error message:

`fatal: Could not change back to '/usr/local/www': No such file or directory`

The strange thing is if I run `cd ../` I can run `git init` on the `/usr/local` directory without any issues. However if I follow that up with a `git status` the `www` directory is not visible.

This is the output I get as a result of running `git status` on the `/usr/local` directory:

```
On branch master 

Initial commit   

Untracked files: 
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        bin/     
        etc/     
        include/ 
        info/    
        lib/     
        libdata/ 
        libexec/ 
        sbin/    
        share/
```

Is there any particular reason git cannot locate the `www` directory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a physical folder or a symbolic link? is it inside your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @codeWizard it is a pysical folder & I don't have a gitignore file.

Comment: Does your parent directory already have a .git folder inside? meaning if the parent dire is also a git repo

Comment: The `usr/local` dir did - I have removed the `.git` directory but the issue still persists..

Comment: what is the output of:
'ls -la /usr/local'
command?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comments:

Looks like you have the folder in your global ignored file.
search for the file `.gitignore` all over your OS and verify that you don't have the `www` as ignored folder.

#### How to verify if the folder is ignored?

- Rename the folder and run git status to see if it appear in the status log
- Search the OS for all the ignored files and verify that the folder is not in any of them.

  ```
  sudo updatedb
  locate .gitignore
  ```